# What is the best way to convert a PDF file to PNG using RMagick and keep high quality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

In my Rails app I wants to convert a PDF to PNG using Rmagick gam.
I found those lines do the trick:

```
require 'RMagick'
pdf = Magick::ImageList.new("file_name.pdf")
pdf.each_with_index do |page_img, i|
   page_img.write("#{i}.png")
end
```

BUT the output PNG file is in not in good quality (the source is good), is there a way to improve it?

Answer (score 3):

A PDF is usually a vector graphics file. To read it as a raster image, a resolution/density needs to be specified. The usual density used is 72 which is a bit low (probably OK for Web thumbnails). If you change the ImageList line to

`pdf = Magick::ImageList.new("file_name.pdf") {self.density="300"}`

That seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a block to the [new method](https://rmagick.github.io/ilist.html#new) which sets the quality attribute. (This sets the attributes for [Image::Info](https://rmagick.github.io/info.html))

```
require 'RMagick'
pdf = Magick::ImageList.new("file_name.pdf") do
        # Adjust quality (default 75)     
        self.quality = 100
      end
pdf.each_with_index do |page_img, i|
  page_img.write("#{i}.png")
end
```